# Get ALL photos from a facebook album (PHP API)

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've got a problem with my source code. I've don't used since... 8/9 months and now, it doesn't work anymore.

I'm looking to list all my photos in my albums BUT, now it's listing me just 25 photos of each album and not more. I've got 100/200/250 photos per albums (party shootings) and I want to list them for my own website (to use Facebook bandwidth)

Here is my source code :

```
<?php 
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include_once('facebook.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Albums</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$params = array(
    'appId' => APP_ID,
    'secret' => APP_SECRET,
);
$facebook = new Facebook($params);
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$log = null;

if ($user) {
    $log = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
    $log = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_photos'));
}
echo '<a href="'.$log.'">' . (($user) ? 'logout' : 'login') . '</a>';
    if ($user) {
        $data = $facebook->api(
            '/me/albums',
            'GET',
            array(
                'fields' => 'id,name,privacy,photos.fields(id,name,images)',
                'limit' => '300'
            )
        );

        foreach ($data['data'] as $album) {
            echo '<div>';
                echo '<h3>' . $album['name'] . ' ' . $album['privacy'] . '</h3>';
                echo '<textarea style="width: 800px; height: 500px;">';
                    foreach ($album['photos']['data'] as $photo) {
                                echo $photo['images'][0]['source'].'';
                    }
                echo '</textarea>';

                echo '<textarea style="width: 800px; height: 500px;">';
                    foreach ($album['photos']['data'] as $photo) {
                               echo $photo['images'][7]['source'].'';
                    }
                echo '</textarea>';
            echo '</div>';
            //break;
        }
    }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

So if you're testing this code, you'll see that it listing to you all your albums but not all the pictures, it stops to 25.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use limit in the wrong place. Try-

```
$data = $facebook->api(
           '/me/albums',
           'GET',
           array(
               'fields' => 'id,name,privacy,photos.fields(id,name,images).limit(300)',
               'limit' => '50'
           )
       );
```

In this case, FB will limit your albums to 50 and the photos within your albums to 300.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tested your code but it returns me a white page. No listing of anything.
I saw on the net before sleeping that FB limits now the listing to 25 items. I'm looking for changing this value anywhere or trying to use FQL to get my pictures.